# nextjs-toploader loads infinite with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js14

When I use html2canvas to save the image, the toploader starts to load but it never stops even the image is downloaded. How should I fix such problem?

Using next.js 14.1

LoadingBar.js imported in layout.js

```
"use client";

import NextTopLoader from "nextjs-toploader";

export default function LinearLoadingBar() {
  return <NextTopLoader height={2} showSpinner={false} />;
}
```

page.js

```
  const handleShare = async () => {
    const canvas = await html2canvas(boxRef.current, {
      width: 345,
      height: 500,
      scale: 2,
      useCORS: true,
    });

    const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = image;
    link.download = `${profile.character_name}_${dayjs().format(
      "YYYYMMDD"
    )}`;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  };
```